# Rotate only graph to landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, telerik

In view controller, I have `tableView` and `graphView`. When I change the orientation of device to landscape mode, only the `graphView` should show up in the landscape mode. Please advice:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your "graph view" a separate view controller and then have something like that: "Parent view controller" -[has as a child]-> "Graph view controller" and "Parent view controller" -[has as a child]-> "Table view controller". Once you have that done, you should have disabled rotations for the parent controller and for the table view controller, whilst enabled - for the graph view controller. If this setup seems confusing or the rotation handling callbacks aren't being called, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23821631/2799410.